# AngularJS - Service is not getting registered when not in app.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have done this in the past, but this time it keeps failing, not sure where I am going wrong. below are my files

app js

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module("ScmCodeViewer", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/gitlab", {
                templateUrl: "gitlab.html",
                controller: "gitlabController"
            });
    });

}());
```

Service js

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module("ScmCodeViewer");

    app.factory("gitlabService", function ($http) {
        ....
        }
        return {
            getFiles: getFiles
        }
    });

});
```

when I try to use the gitlabService in my controller like below, I am getting the "unknown provider" error

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module("ScmCodeViewer");
    app.controller("gitlabController", function ($scope, $log, gitlabService) {


            gitlabService.someMethod();
        }
    });

}());
```

however if I move the code in service js to app js and register the service there it seems to work fine.

html

```
<head>
    <script src="scripts/external/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/external/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/gitLabService.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/gitlabController.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: post the order how you have registered index.html

Comment: added the index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to execute your service js. You need the `();` at the end to make sure the function runs.

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module("ScmCodeViewer");

    app.factory("gitlabService", function ($http) {
        ....
        }
        return {
            getFiles: getFiles
        }
    });

})(); //right here you need the ()
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! It was silly of me to miss something simple like that.

Comment: We all do it :)